# Selective updates?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to selectively update fields for a given object? It's a headache having to save all field data if your app only deals with a few of them. In our case, we only want to support changing a few customer and invoice fields on our side. I know the docs state that omitted data fields will be deleted from the object. Is there a way around this?

Also, since filtering retrieve calls to return specific fields is possible, it would only make sense to allow the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In V3, this will be possible using 'sparse update' operation. But in V2 APIs, this operation is no supported.

Ref Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/020_key_concepts/050_sparse_update

V3 docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3

V3 Early Access pgm - https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/06/21/application-is-live-v3-early-adopter-program-july-group/

Thanks